# How can I convert the NSURL json information to a string?

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsurl

I am trying to convert the json file I am retrieving from google's api into a string, but I am stuck on what to do after. Any help is appreciated.

```
let city = NSURL(string: (dict["results"]![0]["address_components"]!![1]["long_name"] as? String)!)!
let state = NSURL(string: (dict["results"]![0]["address_components"]!![3]["short_name"] as? String)!)!
print(city as? String) //warning NSURL to String always fails. 
print(state as? String)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var city = ""
if let addressComponets = (((dict as? NSDictionary)?["results"] as? NSArray)?[0] as? NSDictionary)?["address_components"] as? NSArray{
    if let longName = (addressComponets[1] as? NSDictionary)?["long_name"] as? String{
        city = longName
    }
}
```

Consider using [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) to deal with your json data.

Answer (score -1):

I use [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) to handle JSON object in swift.
It's quite simple and handy:

```
let json = JSON(data)
let value = json["key"].stringValue
```

(I also use [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) for API requests, it is easier than NSURLs)